# Identifying an exponential distribution

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution

If I observe data that has this kind of distribution (e.g. 1 observation has value 10, 4 have value 1.25):

```
n      x 
------------
1      10
2      5
3      2.5 
4      1.25
... 
------------
```

This exponential fits the data well:

```
 x = a * 2^-n
```

What kind of distribution is this? Is it common in some domain?

Comment: Does the order of data matter to you? For instance, if your observations went 10, 1.25, 2.5, 5, the distribution of numbers is identical, but the exponential function does not fit the points $(1, 10)$, $(2, 1.25)$, $(3, 2.5)$, $(4, 5)$. (I think the answer you're looking for is "exponential decay", such as radiation, but I wouldn't call that a "distribution".)

Comment: yes, the order matters, as high values are less frequent than the low ones

Comment: Since all, or very nearly all, discrete distributions are defined on the *lattice* of integers or a subset of them, replace $x$ by $\log_2(10/x)$ (which respects the natural order by reversing it, which is no problem). Now you have a distribution defined on the natural numbers $0,1,2,3,\ldots.$ That should immediately impress upon you that the pattern cannot continue *ad infinitum,* for otherwise the frequencies would diverge and a distribution could not be defined at all. At a minimum, then, you will need to supply a lower cutoff value for $x$ in order to define a distribution.

Comment: To clarify the point by @Dave: a *distribution* describes how often values within a certain interval occur. It seems, however, that you directly measure a *function* $x(n)$, so you are not looking for an exponential distribution (which would be fitted by estimating its parameter &\lamda$), but for fitting an exponential function.

Comment: When you write $n=3$ and $x=2.5$, do you mean that there are three instances of a measurement of $2.5?$

Comment: yes, x is the value and n is the number of observations